# eSocial BX: "Evento não encontrado ou não processado ou sem perfil para acesso"

Tags: xml, api

Estou utilizando o "**Webservice de Solicitação de Download dos Eventos**", o Método "**SolicitarDownloadEventosPorId**". 
Porém, ao enviar o ID do evento, estou obtendo o seguinte retorno:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/download/solicitacao/retorno/v1_0_0">
    <download>
        <retornoSolicDownloadEvts>
            <arquivos>
                <arquivo>
                    <status>
                        <cdResposta>202</cdResposta>
                        <descResposta>Evento não encontrado ou não processado ou sem perfil para acesso.</descResposta>
                    </status>
                    <evt Id="XXXXXXXXXX40000002XXXXXXXXXX44100006"/>
                </arquivo>
            </arquivos>
        </retornoSolicDownloadEvts>
    </download>
</eSocial>
```

Pelo que li na documentação, o ID está correto e o evento está sendo encontrado:

```
201 Evento encontrado.
202 Evento não encontrado ou não processado ou sem perfil para acesso.
401 Número de xxx do evento inválido.
```

Alguém já passou por isso e sabe o que quer dizer "**evento sem perfil para acesso**"? Aparentemente o evento foi processado, então só resta essa alternativa.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiquei que o problema ocorria pois eu estava utilizando a URL de Produção Restrita (ambiente teste). Ao alterar o apontamento para Produção, obtive o retorno correto com os registros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]